# Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: View config not found for name label

Tags: redux-form

I am using the code for redux form mentioned [here](https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/docs/gettingstarted.md/)

But I am getting the Invariant Violation error. Can someone help

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Redux form with React Native, don't use the `Form` component provided by Redux-form, it is not needed anyway. Use the handleSubmit props to submit the form.